# How can you generate the publish preview file with SSDT

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to create a powershell script to publish a database from a database project in visual studio and one of the things I would like to do is show the publish preview you get from visual studio before actually publishing the database. When using visual studio if you open the publish profile and click publish it generates this preview and then publishes the database without any pause or wait. You can also get this preview if you use the generate script feature. What I'm looking for is a way to generate this preview without generating the script or automatically publishing to the database regardless of what the preview says. I know you can use the deploy report via the command line but I was hoping to be able to use the preview since it is easier to read than the xml file. Is there a way to just generate this preview?

Answer (score 1):

The answer, unfortunately, is no.  That output is not otherwise available.